# Binary Search takes long time with vectors

Tags: c++, time-complexity, binary-search

I implemented the Binary Search algorithm in c++ using vectors because the length of the array was not fixed. However, the vector implementation took a longer time than the other implementation where I used arrays. Can someone help me understand why this happened?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int BinSearch(long long int arr[],int key,int l,int r)
{
    if(r<l){return -1;}
    int mid = (l+r)/2;
    if(arr[mid]==key){return mid;}
    else if(arr[mid] < key)
    {
        return BinSearch(arr,key,mid+1,r);
    }
    else{return BinSearch(arr,key,l,mid-1);}
}

int main()
{
    int n,k;
    cin >> n;
    long long int N[n];
    long long int inp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> inp;
        N[i] = inp;
    }
    cin >> k;
    long long int keys[k],ans[k];
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cin >> inp;
        keys[i] = inp;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        ans[i] = BinSearch(N,keys[i],0,n-1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cout << ans[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The only difference between the vector implementation and array implemetation was that I used vector to store the given numbers on which the binary search is to be performed and to store the keys as well. I used the pushback() operation.

Comment: Not without seeing any code, or knowing what options you used to compile the code. Many vector implmentations include debugging checks that slow code down unless you compile with suitable optimization settings. Or you could have simply made a mistake in your vector implementation. Finally binary search is very fast, it's quite difficult to get relaible timings, so we would also need to know how you got your timings.

Comment: Since, it's a common mistake. Please make sure that you have sorted the `vector` and if you have then please share your implementation.

Comment: @AyushMahajan There's a constraint on the input method where the numbers are entered in an increasing order only.

Comment: Is it an infinite loop or just taking longer to calculate? What I do when I am stuck in infinite loops with Binary Search is that I print values of `low` and `high` and check if they ever stop moving towards the exit condition.

Comment: No not an infinite loop, With an input array of size 10^4 the vectorized implementation took considerably longer than array implementation.

Comment: "The only difference is..." please show the actual code. `push_back` can be expensive, but not if you `reserve` first. Passing by value would be very expensive as well - need to see if you're doing that.

Comment: What means "considerably longer"? What exactly takes longer, the binary search or something else? I think your code example above won't compile because you declare an int-array with variable size: `long long int N[n];` If you have a fixed-size-array it is placed on the stack. A vector is placed on the heap. The stack is faster.